# Adding onClick to listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` and I want to run a function according to the clicked value on `ListView` for now i just want to know only how to get and toast the value I was trying to do it but don't know the proper code... please check my code.

```
public class SubCategory extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ListView listView;
String buttonType;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana"};
static final String[] NAMES = new String[] { "Sachin", "Brett", "Shane", "Zaheer"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_category);



    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null) {
        buttonType = bundle.getString("BUTTON_CLICKED");
    }
    if(buttonType != null && buttonType.equals("A")) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, FRUITS);
    } else if(buttonType != null && buttonType.equals("B")) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, NAMES);
    }
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

     public void getList() {

        Toast.makeText(listView.getContext(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.listview:
                getList();
                break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` instead of `OnClickListener ` to get ListView row clicks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK can you show editing my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String value="";
      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(buttonType) && buttonType.equals("A")) {
          value=FRUITS[position];
       } else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(buttonType) && buttonType.equals("B")) {
          value=NAMES[position];
       }
     // you can get value in "value"
       showToast(value);
    }
});
public void showToast(String value) {

    Toast.makeText(this,value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks... I got it.

Answer (score 3):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        list.get(position).GET_INFORMATION(); //GET_INFORMATION will be the method in your POJO class
    }
});
```

Comment: It gives an error check out this [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aryb3b50a4mt159/error.png?dl=0).

Comment: which file you're writing this code on? This will come in your activity class after listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: yes i am writing it just there below listView.setAdapter(adapter); and under onCreat function.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the support. :)

Answer (score 1):

To add click listener to listview follow these steps

1.add click listener like this in oncreate method of the activity.

`listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

2.Implement OnItemClickListener in the activity.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

3.Override the onItemClick method in the activity.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    //Call method here
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the support. :)